# PHP Illegal offset type

Tags: php, warnings

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in /email_HANDLER.php on line 85

$final_message = str_replace($from, $to, $final_message);

preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$final_message, $result);
$img = array();
foreach($result as $img_tag)
{
    preg_match_all("/(alt|title|src)=('[^']*')/i",(string)$img_tag, $img[$img_tag]); //LINE 85
}
```

Anyone? I'm about to tear my hair out over this...

here is my var_dump of $img_tag

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(97) "<img alt='' src='http://pete1.netsos.com/site/files/newsletter/banner.jpg' align='' border='0px'>"
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is the result of something like a node operation with SimpleXML?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming `$img_tag` is an object of some type, rather than a proper string, cast `$img_tag` to a string inside the `[]`

```
preg_match_all("/(alt|title|src)=('[^']*')/i",(string)$img_tag, $img[(string)$img_tag]);
//------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

Some object types, notably `SimpleXMLElement` for example, will return a string representation to `print/echo` via the [magic method `__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring), but cannot stand in as regular strings.  Attempts to use them as array keys will yield the `illegal offset type` error unless you cast them to proper strings via `(string)$obj`.

Comment: now when I add (string) to those two locations, it does not give the strings I need when I print_r $img....which is the image locations, any ideas?

Comment: Post `print_r($result)` so we can see what you're starting with.

Comment: This is worth looking at, too. Good call, I had never ran into this before. http://us3.php.net/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 10):

See first comment on [this PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40583):

> You cannot use arrays or objects as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type. Check your code.

Ensure that `$img_tag` is of the appropriate variable type.

Answer (score 2):

`$result` is 2-dimentional array.So, `$img_tag` should be an array.

But only integers and strings may be used as offset

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $result[0] as $img_tag)
```

it works

Comment: this is the solution for me