# Illegal offset type php function

Tags: php

I got this code and I am having trouble because of illegal offset type.

```
function getChildren($xmlSet){

    global $output;

    if(is_object($xmlSet)){

         if(count($xmlSet->children()) > 0){

             foreach($xmlSet->children() as $i => $child){
                  if($child->getName() === "label"){
                       $output[(string)$xmlSet->attributes()['id']] = getChildren($child);
                  } else {
                       if($child->getName() === "field" || $child->getName() === "fieldset"){

                            $output[$xmlSet->attributes()['id']] = getChildren($child);
                       }
                  }
             }
```

Comment: what is issue ? what you are expecting and what you are getting ?

Comment: what line specifically gives you the error?

Comment: this part -> $output[$xmlSet->attributes()['id']] = getChildren($child);

Comment: change to `$output[(string)$xmlSet->attributes()['id']] = getChildren($child);`

Comment: @liujinlong if this fixed your issue, please accept my answer. Your acceptance is our only payment, and it also helps future users to the site identify helpful solutions.

Comment: I did that but now It makes an infinite loop that crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this once

```
 $output[(string)$xmlSet->attributes()['id']] = getChildren($child);
```

but the second time you have

```
 $output[$xmlSet->attributes()['id']] = getChildren($child);
```

The first time did an explicit cast to a string, but the second did so implicitly, hence the warning.

> Some object types, notably `SimpleXMLElement` for example, will return a string representation to print/echo via the magic method `__toString()`, but cannot stand in as regular strings. Attempts to use them as array keys will yield the illegal offset type error unless you cast them to proper strings via `(string)$obj` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732130/1938889))

Comment: So what will be the solution? I tried inserting a (string) but it end up making it an infinite loop/ memory overload

Comment: Use an explicit `(string)` cast: `$output[(string)$xmlSet->attributes()['id']] = getChildren($child);` just like your first code that did the same thing.

Comment: @liujinlong Why did you change the accept suddenly 2 months later?

Comment: @liujinlong Yes, you did. That's why I was notified you unaccepted my answer. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to access an array element via a simpleXml object. Before you can access the array element you must cast it to a scalar type value.

So change this:

```
$output[$xmlSet->attributes()['id']] = getChildren($child);
```

To this:

```
$output[(string)$xmlSet->attributes()['id']] = getChildren($child);
```