# Sort XML rows alphabetically by one node, using PHP

Tags: php, xml, sorting, alphabetical

This is an example of my XML:

```
<ROW>
<DEPT_CODE>11111</DEPT_CODE>
<DEPARTMENT>Program Name</DEPARTMENT>
<BLDG_CODE>BLCG</BLDG_CODE>
<ADDR_STREET1>123 Main Street</ADDR_STREET1>
<ADDR_STREET2>Suite 456</ADDR_STREET2>
<ADDR_STREET3>Lower Level</ADDR_STREET3>
<ADDR_CITY>New York</ADDR_CITY>
<ADDR_STATE>NY</ADDR_STATE>
<ADDR_ZIP>101010</ADDR_ZIP>
<PHONE>212-555-1234</PHONE>
<FAX>212-555-5678</FAX>
<EMAIL>email@company.com</EMAIL>
<URL>http://www.company.com</URL>
</ROW>
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('department.xml');
foreach($xml->children() as $depts) {
echo $depts->DEPARTMENT . "<br />";
}
?>
```

It correctly outputs the list of departments, in the order they appear in the XML, but I want it to sort alpha by DEPARTMENT node.

Comment: that's how it's supposed to be. the order you get data out of DOM is the order that things appeared in the original xml. If you want a specific ordering, you'd have to impose that yourself: fetch the department names, store in array, sort the array, output. or generate the xml with that ordering already in place.

Comment: you could also format the output with a stylesheet - apply the transformations and sorting in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the above answers seemed to show a piece of what I ended up with, but I'm adding the final results in case it's helpful to someone else:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
foreach($xml->children() as $departments) {
    (string)$collect[(string)$departments->DEPT_NAME]=$departments;
}

usort ($collect, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->DEPT_NAME, $b->DEPT_NAME);
});

echo "<ul>";
    foreach($collect as $departments) {
        if ($departments->DEPT_NAME != "") {
            echo "<li>" . $departments->DEPT_NAME . "</li>";
        }
    }
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If all DEPARTMENTs are unique do:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('department.xml');
foreach($xml->children() as $depts) {
  $collect[(string)$depts->DEPARTMENT]=$depts;
}
ksort($collect);
foreach($collect as $depts) {
  echo $depts->DEPARTMENT . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: This works, with one small edit. At first I received a "Warning: Illegal offset type" on the `$collect` line. [I read about that here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732109/php-illegal-offset-type) and then adjusted that line as follows:

`(string)$collect[(string)$depts->DEPARTMENT]=$depts;`

And it works great!!
Please modify your answer so I can mark it correct.

Comment: I'm applying this same method to employees, and I'm finding that ksort is case sensitive, and there are three employees who have last names which start with lower case letters. When I try natcasesort, it's entirely out of order ... thoughts? Also, @justonundermillions see above comment to tweak your answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: Also @JustOnUnderMillions ksort strips out any employees with the same last name. Any thoughts?

Comment: `(string)$depts` done, this `(string)$collect` is not needed, because the result of typecast to string isnt used anywhere and `$collect` will be still an array after the line.

Comment: And `ksort` just orders the keys of the array, removing nothing, and   as i noted if you have two element with the same `DEPARTMENT` the last will be overriden by the next. eg `$a['key']=1; $a['key']=2; $a['key']=3;` result `['key'=>3]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the example matches your XML. It contains only a single ROW, so sorting it would make no sense. Let's say you have something like:

```
<records>
  <ROW>
    <DEPT_CODE>11111</DEPT_CODE>
    <DEPARTMENT>Program Name DEF</DEPARTMENT>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <DEPT_CODE>12222</DEPT_CODE>
    <DEPARTMENT>Program Name ABC</DEPARTMENT>
  </ROW>
</records>
```

You will need to fetch all `ROW` elements first. SimpleXML adds a lot of interfaces and syntax magic. But `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` can return an array of objects. After you got an array you can use `uasort()` to sort it with a compare function.

```
$records = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$list = $records->xpath('/*/ROW');
uasort(
  $list,
  function($one, $two) {
    return strcasecmp($one->DEPARTMENT, $two->DEPARTMENT);
  } 
);

var_dump($list);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
    ["DEPT_CODE"]=>
    string(5) "12222"
    ["DEPARTMENT"]=>
    string(16) "Program Name ABC"
  }
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["DEPT_CODE"]=>
    string(5) "11111"
    ["DEPARTMENT"]=>
    string(16) "Program Name DEF"
  }
}
```

*btw* In DOM it would look like this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$list = iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate('/*/ROW'));
uasort(
  $list,
  function($one, $two) use ($xpath) {
    return strcasecmp(
      $xpath->evaluate('string(DEPARTMENT)', $one), 
      $xpath->evaluate('string(DEPARTMENT)', $two)
    );
  } 
);

var_dump($list);
```

Comment: Well, the sample XML was just structural. There is of course more than one department. I'll review and test your solution as well. Thank you for weighing in!

Comment: I tried this, but received the following errors:
`Warning: simplexml_load_string() []: Entity: line 58: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in test2.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_string() []: in test2.php on line 59

Warning: simplexml_load_string() []: ^ in test2.php on line 59

Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in test2.php on line 60`

Comment: The XML you're loading is invalid/broken.

Comment: It outputs fine using other methods, it just refuses to sort alpha, so I tried this one too.

Comment: The error happens before any of the sort logic is executed. The error message clearly reports that the XML can not be loaded. That has nothing to do with the sort.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. However, what I am saying is that I have used the xml with other attempts (ex: the answer below this) and the xml works fine. I can output the node contents in any manner I like, but cannot sort by the correct node.

Comment: I don't know your source - the error is reported in line 59 in you PHP file, for loading the XML. Maybe you load a different XML or you load a file name as string or something else.